# Foo2capt -Canon LBP2900 printer configuration

Tags: printing, 13.04, canon

How can configure Canon LBP2900 printer using foo2capt driver downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/foo2capt/ in Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/foo2capt

Note it only works with LBP-2900, LBP-2900B, and Canon LBP-3000 so far.

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/foo2capt/foo2capt
cd foo2capt
# install build deps if necessary
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev libcupsimage2-dev
# build binary package
dpkg-buildpackage -b
# install it
sudo dpkg -i ../cups-driver-capt_*.deb
```

Comment: Please explain steps after installation of foo2capt driver to set up Canon LBP 2900 printer